# Can't use Material style

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to use [Material's styling](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) but Typescript is throwing an error:

```
import React from 'react';
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});

const Hook = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
};

export default Hook;
```

The error is from the useStyles:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'never' has no call signatures.

const useStyles: never
```

It's probably an issue with my TS config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es2017",
      "ES6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": [
        "src/components/*",
      ],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Rob apologies, didn't consider that search engines wouldn't track the error this way. My bad, edited the question.

Comment: Which line does it have the error?

Comment: The useStyles declaration in the component

Answer (score 3):

The `makeStyles` function is deprecated in Material UI v5.  Your question shows a correct import from the "old" v4 package.  But I suspect that you might be importing from the new v5 package in your actual code, either in this file or elsewhere.

---

Due to the deprecation of the function, you cannot use either of the following imports:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/material';
```

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

These will import a function with the type signature:

```
export default function makeStyles(stylesCreator: any, options?: object): never;
```

Which causes your error:

> TS2349: This expression is not callable.   Type 'never' has no call signatures.

---

Due to the change in package names from `@material-ui` to `@mui`, you can use v4 and v5 alongside each other as long as you are importing from the correct package.  You can still use `makeStyles` if you are importing from the old package:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

Of course the other option is to rewrite your code to use the new `sx` method of styling.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed to set `makeStyles` a arrow function.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

i see that you declare a function instead of a componente because you need to put "{}" inside of () where you have to put params.
try with this.

```
 const Hook = ({}) => {
  ....
 };
```